# Remove key from JSON dynamically in golang

Tags: json, string, go

I have a varying JSON schema (`json.RawMessage`) that can have an arbitrary format. I do not know the format at compile time.

In golang, I would like to check if in the root-JSON object a key exists and if so remove that key completely and deserialize.

So for example, say I need to remove "foo" if it exists

```
{ "foo": [1,2,3], "bar123":"baz"} -> {"bar123":"baz" }
{ "foo": "test", "bar123":"baz"} -> { "bar123":"baz" } 
{ "foo": {"bar":"bar2"}, "bar123":"baz"} -> { "bar123":"baz" }
{ "bar123":"baz"} -> { "bar123":"baz" }
{ "foo": {"bar":"bar2"}} -> {}
```

Given that I need to know the structure of the JSON in advance for serializing and deserializing, how can I do this with go?

Comment: @icza correct sorry, fixed

Comment: You know at least that you're dealing with a JSON object, unmarshal into `map[string]json.RawMessage` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may unmarshal into a value of type `interface{}` if you don't know anything about the JSON. The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will choose `map[string]interface{}` for JSON objects, and `[]interface{}` for JSON arrays.

You may use a type assertion to check if the result is a map, and you may remove the `"foo"` key from it, then marshal it again:

For example:

```
inputs := []string{`{ "foo": [1,2,3], "bar":"baz"}`,
    `{ "foo": "test", "bar123":"baz"}`,
    `{ "foo": {"bar":"bar2"}, "bar123":"baz"}`,
    `{ "bar123":"baz"}`,
    `{ "foo": {"bar":"bar2"}}`,
}

for _, input := range inputs {
    var i interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &i); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if m, ok := i.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        delete(m, "foo") // No problem if "foo" isn't in the map
    }

    output, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TZ_yJdIeG0a)):

```
{"bar":"baz"}
{"bar123":"baz"}
{"bar123":"baz"}
{"bar123":"baz"}
{}
```

If you're sure the input is a JSON object, you can unmarshal directly into a map of type `map[string]interface{}` (or even better: into `map[string]json.RawMessage`), and so the code will be simpler:

```
var m map[string]json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
delete(m, "foo")
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I77MfCbDA21).

Another optimization is to check if the key `"foo"` is actually in the map, and only delete it and marshal the modified map if it is so. Else the input will be the output (no change is required):

```
var m map[string]json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

output := input
if _, exists := m["foo"]; exists {
    delete(m, "foo")
    outputData, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    output = string(outputData)
}

fmt.Println(output)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HZjp_VEfK-u).

Answer (score 2):

Personally i love to use [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) module which allows to handle those kind of situation in a more human friendly way.

---

For installing the module use:

```
go get github.com/Jeffail/gabs/v2
```

---

So, for remove keys dinamicaly if exists

```golang
// jsonParsed var contains a set of functions to play arround
jsonParsed, _ := gabs.ParseJSON([]byte(`{
    "outter":{
        "inner":{
            "value1":10,
            "value2":22
        },
        "alsoInner":{
            "value1":20
        }
    }
}`))

// for this case, it's useful Exists or ExistsP functions
exists := jsonParsed.Exists("outter", "inner", "value1")
// exists == true

exists = jsonParsed.ExistsP("outter.inner.value3")
// exists == false

// for delete a key ... you can use Delete or DeleteP functions.
// this validate for you whether or not the key exists
jsonParsed.DeleteP("outter", "inner")

// and check it with a nice pretty-print
fmt.Println(jsonParsed.StringIndent("", "  "))
// "outter: {
//     "alsoInner: {
//        "value: 20
//     }
// }
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs)